# rsync backup files to remote server with find command

Tags: linux, shell, rsync

im using this ( part of my script) to do backup remotly

```
backupservers="mybackupserver1.server.com mybackupserver2.server.com "

BACKUP_DIR="/var/backups/"

cd ${BACKUP_DIR}
for DST in ${backupservers}
do
        rsync -av -e -i `ls-1t | head -2` @${DST}:/var/backups/
done
```

its read files in backupdirs and take latest 2 files modified/added and send them to backup servers , 
ive changed backupdirs now it include sub dires , 
how i can adjust the script to do  find files which modified in last 2 hrs and rsync these files only , find recursvery and rysnc output files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` to get a list of files modified in the last 2 hours:

`find . -type f -mtime -2h`

To rsync recursively, use the `-r` flag.

All together:

```
rsync -avrc -e -i `find . -type f -mtime -2h` @${DST}:/var/backups/
```

Comment: Those are not valid rsync flags, *-e* needs to be followed by the name of an *ssh* replacement, and will try to transfer the files by calling *-i*.  Besides which, that command will fail as soon as you hit a file with a space in it's name.